# Laravel 5.4 upload multiple images with validation rules

Tags: validation, file-upload, laravel-5.4

I'm using following code to upload multiple images but I need to add some validation rules like file should be an image with mentioned extensions and file size. Currently it upload everything.

This is my html view code:

```
<input required="" type="file" name="photos[]" id="photos" multiple="" directory="" webkitdirectory="" mozdirectory="">
```

This is my controller code:

```
foreach ($request->photos as $photo) {
    $filename = $photo->store('photos');
    $data['photoName'] = $filename;
    PhotosModel::SavePhotos($data);
    $message = "Photos Added Successfully";
}
```

I've added below code inside foreach loop and before that loop to but it's giving error that photos must be an image and of mentioned types.

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'photos' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:2048'
]);
```

I want to upload all images and stop other files from being uploaded. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this (before your foreach):

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'photos' => 'required',
    'photos.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:2048'
]);
```

Comment: I've tried that, it worked but I need if user upload 20 images and 1 pdf, it should upload those images but skip pdf.